# CSS - a:hover:before - How to include this :before content in the 'hover zone'?

Tags: html, css

I'm not quite sure how to word this question, but I am trying to create a link, so when you hover, a bullet is placed before the link.

However, this doesn't work because the `:before` content is not part of the hover area and thus the link vibrates infinitely as a result when hovering on the `:before` area of the link.

[This jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ukowuy/1/) illustrates the problem.

Is there a CSS solution to solve this problem?

Comment: It should be included in the hover zone since it's technically part of the element. What browser are you observing this behavior in?

Comment: It seems to work fine for me. Make sure to view this in IE9 or higher, Lastest Firefox, safari or chrome.

Comment: In IE9, Chrome and FF it works like expected for me. On hover two red stars are added before the link.

Comment: Sorry, to make it more clear, try hovering on the left side of the link. I am using the latest version of Chrome (23.0.1271.95). Also observing this problem in Safari. It works fine in FF though.

I've made a quick video demonstrating this: [Video Link](http://cloud.alanwoo.ca/E0Mf/N6AgK8Aa)